# Не работает BIOS после установки Ubuntu

Tags: windows, netbios, ubuntu

Проблема, ноутбук Lenovo G580, установил Ubuntu 13.10 теперь не могу войти в BIOS, до этого стояла Windows 8. Что делать ???

*"первая идея пришедшая в голову, эта выкинуть его на свалку"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема решена !**

Требуемые действия:

1. Выпаять из материнки флешку с BIOS
2. Пере прошить на программаторе

За всю работу мой знакомый взял с меня 40$

> После чего посоветовал больше неставить LINUX, потому как у этоймодели (Lenovo G580) опять слетит всенафиг.

Классные нынче компы стали делать, покупаешь думаешь хорошая вещь, оказывается кирпич )

Comment: Какая прелесть!!! Вот так они и делают! UEFI, я теперь в этом точно убедился - это происки Мелкомягких, с целью не допустить стороннего софта! Ну, ничего страшного... И это ломается! Возможно, что уже...

Comment: Совет откровенно идиотский.

Answer (score 3):

А там вообще-то не BIOS, а UEFI, который умеет эмулировать BIOS в режиме "legacy". Как вам удалость снести UEFI - не знаю, но попробуйте вот тут пообщаться: http://forums.lenovo.com/lnv/?profile.language=en

Comment: Снести получилось очень просто, достаточно на такой кирпичь как Lenovo G580 поставить Linux и все, прощай кирпичь !

Comment: Может можно как то загрузится с флешки хотя бы, без запуска этого UEFI, может у Linux найдется такая вещь как у windows 8, при загруженной ОС выбрать с чего будет загружаться комп после перезагрузки ???

Comment: По идее, там должна быть возможность восстановления с дискеты, да и не только! Посмотрите здесь: http://support.lenovo.com/ru_RU/downloads/default.page? Вообще-то могли бы и сами это найти!

Comment: А в Линуксе есть свой загрузчик - GRUB. Вот с UEFI у него проблема конкретная, новроде теперь поправили.

Comment: На всякий пожарный посоветую ещё SuperGrub Disk, это здесь: http://freecode.com/projects/supergrub?branch_id=62132&release_id=249273

Comment: Хм. У меня тоже Lenovo, только TP Edge E530 (i5, 500GB, 4GB+4GB, noOS) установлена на нем Russian Fedora Remix - поэтому даже не представляю, что можно было сделать, чтоб снести UEFI?  @kostya - не просветите на этот счет? В порядке самообразования...

Comment: Сносится очень просто, ставишь от сюда дистрибутив http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop и прощай UEFI? После этого получается два варианта, первый это когда UEFI вроде как живой, но войти в него не будет возможности, второй вариант, это когда этот UEFI слетает нафиг, комп грузится, но если слетит последняя живущая на нем ОС, то получается качественный "кирпич" )

Answer (score 3):

Boot Repair !!!

Работает под Linux, в том числе с Live CDВосстанавливает и UEFIОписание:http://www.linux-info.ru/boot-repair.htmlReviews:http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/Downloads:http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/

На будующее рекомендую с помощью GParted cделать копию раздела sdX1 (System) на внешний HDD (200Mb - 1Gb).Дополнительно для Win-8 можно: - скинуть свои данныа на внешний накопитель - ужать с помощью GParted Win-раздел (64Gb без потери работоспособности Win) - cделать с помощью GParted копию разделов Win и Recovery (10 - 11Gb) на внешний HDDЕсли провести эти операции на новом компе с неактивированной Win-8, то можно стать обладателем клонируемой лицензионной версии.

После всех этих манипуляций - снести Windows с компа и пользоваться своей Ubuntu 13.10, а HDD с копиями 3-х разделов подарить какому-нибудь лузеру.

Answer (score 2):

аналогичная проблема. Просто мне ни разу не понадобился толком BIOS.Попробуй вытащить HDD и загрузиться в BIOS без него.

UPD:
Привет!
Скачай обновление прошивки для BIOS ноута. После этого можно будет заходить в BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Может поможет:

- [Установка дистрибутива на компьютер с efi](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/установка_дистрибутива_на_компьютер_с_efi)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже подобное только на стационаре было, вылечил перезагрузкой биоса. На стационаре делается простым вытаскиванием батарейки с материнской платы( на некоторых моделях где-то читал нужно снимать на пол часа,чтобы перезапустилось, лично у меня просто вытащил и обратно поставил и заработало)