# Восстановить UEFI загрузчик

Tags: ubuntu

Может кто знает как восстановить UEFI загрузчик. Установил Ubuntu теперь не могу попасть в биос. Может есть какая статья как это все делается пошагово.

Модель ноута Lenovo G580, читал на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/169985/) с этой моделью у многих были проблемы после установки linux, но как вернуть UEFI к сожалению не написали.

Comment: Здесь уже была тема по данному вопросу - воспользуйтесь поиском или вот [тема по UEFI](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=167665.0)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает BIOS после установки Ubuntu](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/347274/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-bios-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Смотри вопрос:Не работает BIOS после установки Ubuntuраздел netbios